# Why Material Ui constantly giving error to me?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, typeerror

Iam using material ui and it constantly giving an error to me

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  row: {
    backgroundColor: "#16171a",
    cursor: "pointer",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#131111",
    },
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
  },
});
```

this is my code

and

```
makeStyles.js:156 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'refs')
```

this is the error I getting

Comment: What version of React and MUI?

Comment: @DaveNewton react - 18.2.0 , MUI -   "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@mui/styles": 5.11.2

Comment: https://mui.com/system/styles/api/

Comment: @DaveNewton iam just a beginner so can you explain it ?

Comment: “@mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.”

Comment: @DaveNewton so i need to downgrade the react version right ?